# Decode error: Failure "Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `gamegrid`"

Tags: javascript, json, elm, decoder

I have an issue with my code (ELM / JSON / Python (Flask)), so my problem is,

After receiving a message, My server tries to send a response to the ELM view, through JSON.
My browser's console gets this

```js
0:
currentPlayerId: "0"
firstClickCellId: "-1"
gameOverStatus: "1"
gamegrid: Array(9)
0: {hash: "0", value: "-1"}
1: {hash: "1", value: "-1"}
2: {hash: "2", value: "-1"}
3: {hash: "3", value: "-1"}
4: {hash: "4", value: "-1"}
5: {hash: "5", value: "-1"}
6: {hash: "6", value: "-1"}
7: {hash: "7", value: "-1"}
8: {hash: "8", value: "-1"}
length: 9
__proto__: Array(0)
userToPlayId: "1"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

ButI have this message right after:

```js
Decode error: Failure "Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `gamegrid`" <internals>
```

However, the "gamegrid" field is present in the message received! i can't figure out why it cannot be decoded

I put the code so that you can see what is done before

====================CODE============================================================

This is a part of my Model

```js
type alias Model =
    { 
      users : List User
    , gameOverView: GameOverView
    }
    
type alias GameOverView = 
  {
     gameGrid: List Cell
     ,userToPlayId: String
     ,gameOverStatus : String
     ,firstClickCellId: String
     , currentPlayerId : String
     
  }
  
type alias Cell = 
    {
     hash: String
    ,value: String
    }
```

Here is the Decoder of this part

```js
cellDecoder : Decoder Cell
cellDecoder =
    Decode.map2 Cell
        (Decode.field "hash" Decode.string)
        (Decode.field "value" Decode.string)

listCellDecoder : Decoder (List Cell)
listCellDecoder =
  Decode.list cellDecoder
    
gameOverViewDecoder : Decoder GameOverView
gameOverViewDecoder =
    Decode.map5 GameOverView
        (Decode.field "gamegrid" listCellDecoder)
        (Decode.field "userToPlayId" Decode.string)
        (Decode.field "gameOverStatus" Decode.string)
        (Decode.field "firstClickCellId" Decode.string)
        (Decode.field "currentPlayerId" Decode.string)
```

Here is the JSON decoder

```js
decodeExternalGameOverView : Value -> Msg
decodeExternalGameOverView val =
    case Decode.decodeValue gameOverViewDecoder val of
        Ok gameOverView ->
            GotNewGameOverView gameOverView

        Err err ->
            DecodeError err

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ userlistPort decodeExternalUserlist,
        gameOverViewlistPort decodeExternalGameOverView,
         receiveData ReceivedDataFromJS]
```

Here is the server sending the message (note that he successfuly received a previous message)

```py
@app.route('/updategrid/', methods=['POST'])
@flask_login.login_required
def checkPlay():
    print("+++++++++++++++++++++++")
    firsCellClikId = request.json["firstClickedId"]
    secondCellClikId = request.json["secondClickedId"]
    userToPlayId = request.json["userToPlay"]
    currentPlayerId = request.json["currentPlayerId"]
    gameOverStatus = "1"
    
    g = []
    for i in range(9):
      grid = {}
      grid["hash"]  = str(i)
      grid["value"] = request.json[str(i)]
      g.append(grid)
    print("checking play turn")
    print("firstCell = ", firsCellClikId, " SecondCell = ", secondCellClikId)
    print("UserToplay = ", userToPlayId, " UserPlayed = ", currentPlayerId)
    
    if(userToPlayId == "0"):
      userToPlayId = "1"
    else:
      userToPlayId = "0"
    #for x, y in g.items():
    send = {
      "gamegrid": g,
      "userToPlayId": userToPlayId,
      "gameOverStatus": gameOverStatus,
      "firstClickCellId": "-1",
      "currentPlayerId": currentPlayerId
    }
    print(send)
    io.emit('gamegrid', [
      
        send,
      
    ]
  , broadcast=True)
    print("New grid sent")
    
    return "ok", 201
```

part of the HTML template

```js
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var socket = io();
var app = Elm.Main.init({ node: document.querySelector('#main-content')});
  
socket.on('gamegrid', function(gamegrid){
  console.log("New GameOverView received:", gamegrid);
  app.ports.gameOverViewlistPort.send(gamegrid);
});
```

Summary: the problem remains the following: the javascript console (or rather the elm decoder) does not find the "gamegrid" field while it is present and corresponds to the expected type (Cell list)

Your suggestions are welcome.

Best regards::

Comment: What exactly is the json input that you are passing to decoder? Adding that to the question makes it easier to spot the probable error. Also, if you think the problem lies in your Elm decoders then all the server code is irrelevant and just clutters the post.

Answer (score 4):

I think the error is here:

```
io.emit('gamegrid', [
  
    send,
  
    ]
  , broadcast=True)
```

because you send the `send` dictionary/object as the sole element of an array. You can see this in your console output, and seems to cause the error because arrays have no `gamegrid` property - the property you want is on the contained object.

Replace `[send]` with simply `send` and this ought to work.

Comment: Oh thank you, that was the problem, I thought  sending data to JSON was always inside square brackets [ ], I replaced it with parentheses ( ) and it worked. Thank you.